# Passing an instance of a user defined template class to a non templated function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have following implementation:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename Data, size_t Size> 
class Demo
{  
public:
    Demo();

private:
    Data data[Size];
};

void f(Demo<int, size_t>& demoObj)
{

}


int main()
{
    Demo<int, 100> demoObj;

}
```

I get the following error when I compile:

```
g++ -std=c++11 temp.cpp
temp.cpp:13:24: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class Data, long unsigned int Size> class Demo’
 void f(Demo<int, size_t>& demoObj)
                        ^
temp.cpp:13:24: note:   expected a constant of type ‘long unsigned int’, got ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’
```

The error is not making sense to me. Please help me understand it. Also, how do I pass demoObj to function f? I mean how o write the definition of f.

Comment: The `Size` parameter of `Demo` expects a numeric constant, but in your declaration of `f()`, you are passing it the `size_t` data type instead. That is what the error message is complaining about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Size` is a non-type parameter, so it requires a non-type argument:

```
void f(Demo<int, 100>& demoObj);
//               ^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to pass in any kind of Demo you can define `f` as a template function.

```
template<typename Data, size_t Size>
void f(Demo<Data, Size>& demoObj)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If you want to pass in variable-sized 'Demo<int,' then the template is subtly different.